# Stop loss and profit target as percentage of entry price

Tags: pine-script

In Pine, how can I set up automatic exit if the price goes 5% over or under the price I bought it for?

```
strategy.order("order ID", strategy.long, 1)
strategy.exit("Exit ID", from_entry="ID", ?)
```

What would I put by the `?` to make it limit exit at 5% over/under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strategy.position_avg_price` to get your average price in the position and than calculate your take profit and stop loss accordingly.

Here is a simple example for a long position.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

tp_per = input.float(2.5, "Take profit %") * 0.01
sl_per = input.float(0.5, "Stop loss %") * 0.01

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_per)
long_sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_per)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=long_sl_price, limit=long_tp_price)
```